# upload .json file to firebase database using python

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I want to upload a entire JSON file to my Firebase Database, but I can't get it to run.
I am new to Python and Firebase.

This is my code so far:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint



cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json") 
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)



with open ('/Users/name/Desktop/Test.json') as data_file: data = json.load(data_file)
jsondata = json.dumps('/Users/name/Desktop/Test.json')



requests.put(url="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/", json= jsondata)
```

I get a error : **<Response [400]>**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code that performs the actual write operation:

```
requests.put(url="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/", json= jsondata)
```

This code does not in any way use the Admin SDK, but instead writes directly to the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database.

---

If you want to **write using the REST API**, it is possible, but you'll need to:

1. Ensure your REST call is authenticated, as shown in the documentation on [authenticating REST requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).
2. Use a URL that ends with `.json` to ensure your call end up to the REST API. So:

   ```
    requests.put(url="https://myapp.firebaseio.com/.json", json= jsondata)
   ```

   Yes, that `/.json` at the end of the URL is normal.

---

Alternatively you can continue to **use the Admin SDK to write the data**, but in that case you'll need to read and parse the JSON into your code, and send it to the database as a JavaScript object, as shown in the documentation on [saving data with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-set).

Comment: So I need to implement the REST API (requests) and than it should be working?

Comment: You mostly need to choose to *either* use the REST API *or* the Admin SDK. The way you're now mixing both won't work. I explain what the two options entail in the other two sections of my answer.

Comment: Good to hear @adri567!